# How to create 4 gradient borders div with rounded corners and text

Tags: html, css

I have a div that needs to have rounded corners and colored borders in a particular way: each border has half a color as shown in the picture:

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7rpC.jpg)

I've searched and searched, but I still can't figure out how to make this work for rounded edges.

Could someone guide me with the code?

I have achieved the colored edges using the following code, but not with the rounded edges:

`height: 450px;`
`width: 384px;`
`border: 3px solid transparent;`
`text-align: center;`
`margin: auto !important;`
`border-radius: 16px !important;`
`background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00A0DF 50%, #FFC600 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFC600 50%, #F5333F 50%), linear-gradient(to left, #F5333F 50%, #6ABF4B 50%), linear-gradient(to top, #6ABF4B 50%, #00A0DF 50%);  background-origin: border-box;  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%, 100% 3px, 3px 100%;`  
`background-position: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left;`
`background-repeat: no-repeat; }`

Comment: use the technique in the duplicate and here is the gradient to get the 4 colors `conic-gradient(red 25%,blue 0 50%,green 0 75%,purple 0)` you don't need multiple gradients

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the conic-gradient on the background-image property, the edges are curved but the backgroud its fully colored now.

Sorry, I don't understand this "use the duplicate technique" part. What do you mean?